# How can I improve the code to delete items in an array in the following case?

Tags: ruby, interpolation

I have this code:

```
array = ['notice', 'warning', 'error']

array.delete('notice')  if flash[:notice]
array.delete('warning') if flash[:warning]
array.delete('error')   if flash[:error]
```

Since there are repeated names, in order to shorten the code, I could use the *interpolation* to perform this part of code:

```
array.delete('notice')  if flash[:notice]
array.delete('warning') if flash[:warning]
array.delete('error')   if flash[:error]
```

**How can I do that in one step?**

---

I tryed this

```
array.each { |item|
  array.delete("#{item}") if flash[:"#{item}"]
}
```

but it doesn't work good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you're modifying array over which you iterate.
Something like this should work

```
array.clone.each { |item|
  array.delete("#{item}") if flash[:"#{item}"]
}
```

Try running it with and without `clone` on sample input

```
array = ['notice', 'warning', 'error']
flash = {:warning => 1, :error => 2}

...

p array
```

But there's no need to invoke `delete` manually, you can just user [reject](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000435):

```
array = array.reject! { |item| flash[:"#{item}"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.reject! { |item| flash[item.to_sym] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use string interpolation, just convert the strings to symbols using `.to_sym`:

```
array = ['notice', 'warning', 'error']
array.each { |item|
    array.delete(item) if flash[item.to_sym]
}
```

Or use symbols in `array` to `.to_s` in the delete:

```
array = [:notice, :warning, :error]
array.each { |item|
    array.delete(item.to_s) if flash[item]
}
```